# How can I make space between two buttons in same div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

What is the best way to horizontally space Bootstrap buttons?

At the moment the buttons are touching:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-inverse dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="icon-in-button"></i>  
        Add to list
        <span class="caret"/>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#">here</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">new</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button class="btn btn-info">
        <i class="icon-in-button"></i>  
        more
    </button>
</div>
```

[image: Two Bootstrap buttons]

jsfiddle showing the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/hhimanshu/sYLRq/4/

Comment: I had the same issue and ended adding a margin to one of the buttons-  mr-1 .

Answer (score 354, accepted):

Put them inside `btn-toolbar` or some other container, not `btn-group`. `btn-group` joins them together. More info on Bootstrap [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#buttonGroups).

Edit: The original question was for Bootstrap 2.x, but the same is still valid for [Bootstrap 3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#btn-groups) and [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/button-group/).

In [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/button-group/) you will need to add appropriate margin to your groups using utility classes, such as mx-2.

Comment: I was looking for solution to this problems years ago, why I did not found you previously, you are my hero

Comment: `btn-toolbar` may wrap some buttons to a new line. How to avoid this?

Comment: It's planned to break for responsiveness. If you really want to prevent it from breaking, then set `flex-wrap: nowrap` for `btn-toolbar` in Bootstrap 4 or try with a combination of `overflow` and `white-space` for older Bootstrap versions.

Comment: Is this answer still correct? I'm not seeing any `btn-toolbar` class in BS4 and when looking at the BS4 "Buttons" section, the examples all use custom classes.

Comment: @Svend, look a bit below in "Button group" section - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/button-group/#button-toolbar

Comment: @MiroslavPopovic Thanks, I guess I missed that part (but the answer could perhaps do with some updating, since you do have to use btn-group). I think the extra markup is unneccessary so I'll just create my own custom css.

Comment: btn-toolbar doesn't work in bootstrap 4.  The mx-2 margin class suggestion will work.

Answer (score 87):

Just put the buttons in a class ( class="btn-toolbar" ) as told by bro Miroslav Popovic.It works awesome.

```html
<div class="btn-toolbar">
  <button type="button" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Submit</button>
  <button type="button" id="btnCancel" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use [spacing for Bootstrap](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/spacing/) and no need for any additional CSS. Just add the classes to your buttons. This is for version 4.

Comment: I wanted buttons to appear in a row and allow for them to stack (due to wrapping) on small screens. To achieve spacing that worked both horizontally and vertically, using what bootstrap provides, I did: `className='mb-2 mr-2'`, following @dragan-b's suggestion

Answer (score 11):

What Dragan B suggested is right way to go for Bootstrap 4. I have put one example below. e.g. mr-3 is margin-right:1rem!important

```
<div class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
   <button type="button" class="btn mr-3">btn1</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn mr-3">btn2</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn">btn3</button>
</div>
```

p.s: in my case I wanted my buttons to be displayed to the right of the screen and hence pull-right.

Comment: simply wrapping buttons in `btn-toolbar` fix the space issue!

Answer (score 9):

you should use bootstrap v.4

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="button" class="btn form-control" id="btn1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="button" class="btn form-control" id="btn2">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the best solution for Bootstrap 4 IMO. On smaller screens you can use "px-0 px-sm-2" to get rid of the padding accordingly. Great answer.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way in most situations is margin.

Where you can do :

```
button{
  margin: 13px 12px 12px 10px;
}
```

OR

```
button{
  margin: 13px;
}
```

Comment: Custom margins should not be used when you can place the bootstrap buttons inside the btn-toolbar class.

Answer (score 5):

Dragan B. solution is correct. In my case I needed the buttons to be spaced vertically when stacking so I added the mb-2 property to them.

```
<div class="btn-toolbar">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mr-2 mb-2">First</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mr-2 mb-2">Second</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mr-2 mb-2">Third</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's another approach based on the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/buttons/#block-buttons).

```
 <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex" >
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">button1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">button2</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: only solution that worked for me, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I used the Bootstrap 4 buttons plugin (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#button-plugin)
and added the class *rounded* to the labels and the class *mx-1* to the middle button to achieve the desired look and feel of separate radio buttons. Using the class *btn-toolbar* made the radio button circles appear for me which is not what I wanted. Hope this helps someone.

```
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-secondary active rounded">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Active
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-secondary rounded mx-1">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Radio
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-secondary rounded">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Radio
            </label>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to achieve this is to add a class .btn-space in your buttons

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-space"
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-space"
  </button>
```

and define this class as follows

```
.btn-space {
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I actual ran into the same requirement. I simply used CSS override like this

```
.navbar .btn-toolbar { margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

if use Bootstrap, you can change with style like: If you want only in one page, then betwen head tags add     **.btn-group btn{margin-right:1rem;}**

If is for all the web site add to css file

Answer (score 0):

You could also just put the two buttons in a flexbox and set the gap with css

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" rel="stylesheet">
    <script crossorigin="anonymous"
            integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
            src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
 <div class="d-flex flex-row" style="gap:5px;">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add to list</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">more</button>
 </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I ended up doing something similar to what [mark dibe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48733473/5395858) did, but I needed to figure out the spacing for a slightly different manner.

The `col-x` classes in bootstrap can be an absolute lifesaver. I ended up doing something similar to this:

```
<div class="row col-12">
    <div class="col-3">Title</div>
</div>
<div class="row col-12">
    <div class="col-3">Bootstrap Switch</div>
<div>
```

This allowed me to align titles and input switches in a nicely spaced manner. The same idea can be applied to the buttons and allow you to stop the buttons from touching.

(Side note: I wanted this to be a comment on the above link, but my reputation is not high enough)