# How to give spacing between buttons using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to give spacing between buttons is there a way to give spacing using bootstrap so that they will be consistent for different screen resolutions.

I tried using `margin-left` But is it the correct way to do this.??

Here is the [demo](http://www.bootply.com/dDfIHeZizW)

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-toolbar text-center well">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-color btn-bg-color btn-sm col-xs-2 margin-left">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> ADD PACKET
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-color btn-bg-color btn-sm col-xs-2 margin-left">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span> EDIT CUSTOMER
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-color btn-bg-color btn-sm col-xs-2 margin-left">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" aria-hidden="true"></span> HISTORY
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-color btn-bg-color btn-sm col-xs-2 margin-left">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span> DELETE CUSTOMER
    </button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.margin-left{
    margin-left: 80px !important;
}
```

Comment: Yes it is, or you can use col-sm-offset or something similar

Comment: Button size should be independent. Take a look guys (www.bootply.com/dDfIHeZizW) if I change width of the buttons their alignment gets distorted.

Comment: After trying various solutions and getting feedback from other guys on `##bootstrap IRC` I have decided to go with the `margin-left` for now. Thank you guys...

Comment: this is the right answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11216667/670229

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make space between two buttons in same div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216645/how-can-i-make-space-between-two-buttons-in-same-div)

Answer (score 149):

You can achieved by use bootstrap **Spacing**. Bootstrap Spacing includes a wide range of shorthand responsive margin and padding. In below example `mr-1` set the `margin` or `padding` to `$spacer` * .25.

Example:

```html
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-1" href="#">Sign up</button>
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Login</button>
```

You can read more at [Bootstrap Spacing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/).

Comment: just added mr-1 and boom. Thanks @A.Raza.

Comment: this is for bootstrap4

Comment: Yes, this is for "twbs 4.x".

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for !

Comment: Is `spacer` defined within bootstrap?

Comment: @Brackets Yes its pre-defined.

Comment: This reply must be marked as the correct solution in particular the bootstrap native `mr-*` class which comes from the Spacing https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

Comment: Bootstrap5, you use `m-1` or `ms-1` or `me-1` (start/end)

Comment: that worked but how do I add more space?

Comment: @NikhilS use `m-2`, `m-3` ...

Answer (score 73):

HTML:

```
<input id="id_ok" class="btn btn-space" value="OK" type="button">
<input id="id_cancel" class="btn btn-space" value="Cancel" type="button">
```

CSS:

```
.btn-space {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Even though it wasn't explicitly mentioned, the OP meant they want gutters on buttons in a row. This solution will break bootstrap's grid, causing buttons whose sum takes 100% width to start wrapping.

Answer (score 23):

It varies according to bootstrap version

If you are using

**Bootsrap 4**

> mr-1

for more refer the official  [Bootsrap 4 margin-and-padding link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/utilities-for-layout/#margin-and-padding)

**Bootstrap 5**

> me-1

for more refer the official [Bootsrap 5 margin-and-padding link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/#margin-and-padding)

Comment: Srikrushna,
I was just about to comment that 'mr-1' was not working and then noticed your posting which in my case, being Bootstrap 5 does work when I used me-1.

Thanks for your posting, helped me solve the issue.

Answer (score 14):

1. Wrap your buttons in a div with `class='col-xs-3'` (for example).
2. Add `class="btn-block"` to your buttons.

This will provide permanent spacing.

Comment: But if  I use class='col-xs-2' instead of `class='col-xs-3'` the orientation distorts..

Comment: This also helps when you want the buttons to wrap under each other on smaller resolutions. "To nest your content with the default grid, add a new .row and set of .col-sm-* columns within an existing .col-sm-* column. " - source: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/

Answer (score 11):

If you want use margin, remove the class on every button and use **:last-child** CSS selector.

**Html :**

```
<div class="btn-toolbar text-center well">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-color btn-bg-color btn-sm col-xs-2">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> ADD PACKET
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-color btn-bg-color btn-sm col-xs-2">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span> EDIT CUSTOMER
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-color btn-bg-color btn-sm col-xs-2">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" aria-hidden="true"></span> HISTORY
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-color btn-bg-color btn-sm col-xs-2">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span> DELETE CUSTOMER
    </button>
</div>
```

**Css :**

```
.btn-toolbar .btn{
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.btn-toolbar .btn:last-child{
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: this won't work on mobile with collapsed buttons (each button per row)

Answer (score 6):

I am pretty bad at html but I used `&nbsp;` between the buttons and it worked well.

Comment: Bizarrely, this works much better for me than the more sophisticated solutions above.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on how much space you want. I'm not sure I agree with the logic of adding a "col-XX-1" in between each one, because you are then defining an entire "column" in between each one.

If you just want "a little spacing" in between each button, I like to add padding to the encompassing row. That way, I can still use all 12 columns, while including a "space" in between each button.

Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/ugeXrxpPvD

Comment: @brauliobo add yours as an answer because I believe it's the correct one.

Answer (score 4):

Use `btn-primary-spacing` class for all buttons remove `margin-left` class

Example :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-color btn-bg-color btn-sm col-xs-2 btn-primary-spacing">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> ADD PACKET
</button>
```

CSS will be like :

```
.btn-primary-spacing 
{
margin-right: 5px;
margin-bottom: 5px !important;
}
```

Comment: Where does the class `btn-primary-spacing` come from?

Comment: Looks like a custom implementation. Some code would be nice here

Answer (score 4):

You can use built-in [spacing from Bootstrap](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/spacing/) so no need for additional CSS there. This is for Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 4):

The original code is mostly there, but you need `btn-group`s around each button.  In Bootstrap 3 you can use a btn-toolbar and a btn-group to get the job done; I haven't done BS4 but it has similar constructs.

```
<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button class="btn btn-default">Button 1</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button class="btn btn-default">Button 2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I implemented this, but it does not provide vertical spacing for the buttons, which was noticeable for me when they wrapped onto two lines/"rows".

Comment: If you put them all in a btn-toolbar it's actually enough! eg:
<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar">
    <button class="btn btn-default">Button 1</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default">Button 2</button>
</div>

Answer (score 2):

Adding margins to a button makes it wider so that les buttons fit in the grid system. If only a visual effect is important, then give the button a white border with [style="margin:0px; border:solid white;"] This leaves the button width unaffected.

Answer (score 1):

using bootstrap you can add  `<div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1"></div>` between buttons.