# Bootstrap distance between buttons in navbar

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with bootstrap. I tried to do simple site in django, I created navbar from bootstrap with some buttons depends of user.

It's looks that: 
[image]

And as U can see, the distance between buttons is zero. I tried a margin css as internet say, and even something stupid like adding 'space'. But usually nothing changes. For sure I just do something wrong.
So I decide to ask here. My CSS is basic, I want to learn it but first it I want to end django tutorial, and I stuck here.

My actual code:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/heroes/">SNP list <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/heroes-new">New SNP</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
      <a> Witaj {{ user.username }}  </a>
      {% if request.user.is_staff %}
      <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-success  btn-sm my-2 my-sm-0" href='/admin/'> Panel admina </a>
      {% endif %}
      <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-success  btn-sm my-2 my-sm-0" href='/logout/'> Logout </a>
      {% else %}
      <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm my-2 my-sm-0" href='/login/'> Login </a>
    {% endif %}
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

How can I handle it to make distance between that buttons?

And... what should I know to handling with that problems in future? Should I start from CSS and HTML or it's bootstrap case?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27689927/how-to-give-spacing-between-buttons-using-bootstrap

Comment: `<a> Witaj {{ user.username }}  </a>` try putting the css classes to this tag. and just override the styling with your one custom css class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting margin between elements

```
.navbar-nav li{
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.navbar-nav li:last-child(){
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

You can change the number of `pixels` as you wish.

Use `!important` if style were not overridden.

Comment: Thank u for explain. It works. It mean I need done css course before I can continue django ;0

Answer (score 1):

Use margin in CSS. Use below code in your style

```
.btn{
    margin: 0 5px !important;
}
```