# How do you separate buttons in HTML

Tags: html

I've created a page with 3 buttons on it but all the buttons are stuck side by side and I don't know how to add space in between them.
This is the page so far.

```html
<div style="width: 500px; margin-left: 20px;">
  <a href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9B-lYnsBAPHcFlkT3NQQThpa1E/view?    usp=sharing" target="_blank">
    <input type="submit" name="" value="View Study" />
  </a>
  <a href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9B-lYnsBAPHT2c2MHhJN0l5NlE/view?    usp=sharing" target="_blank">
    <input type="submit" name="" value="View Study" />
  </a>
  <a href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9B-    lYnsBAPHZ0xoTUlnZGZMaWc/view?usp=sharing" target="_blank">
    <input type="submit" name="" value="View Study" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [twitter-bootstrap/HTML/CSS : How can I make space between two buttons in same div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216645/twitter-bootstrap-html-css-how-can-i-make-space-between-two-buttons-in-same-di)

Answer (score 2):

you can add a style for all the buttons with some margins around them like below

```
input[type='button']
{
    margin:10px 10px 10px 10px; //just an example, you can add according to your need
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a class to your div and styling it into your ss instead of hardcoding it into your html. You'll be able to modify all your links via this class later on. If however you must style in your html, simply add this to all your `<a>` tags: **style="margin-right: 10px;"**

Example :

```
<a href="yourlink.html" style="margin-right: 10px;" target="_blank"><input type="submit" name="" value="View Study"/></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just 
 and break the line then in your top  you can just center it or left or right and make it different areas.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.